# Using ggplot to group in two different ways

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have data that looks kinda like this:

```
id = rep(1:33,3)
year = rep(1:3,33)
group = sample(c(1:3),99, replace=T)
test_result = sample(c(TRUE,FALSE), size=99, replace = T)


df = data.frame(id, year, group, test_result)
df$year = as.factor(year)
df$group = as.factor(group)
```

My goal is to visualize it so that I can see how group number and year relate to test_result.

```
df %>% 
    group_by(id,year) %>% 
    summarize(x=sum(test_result)) %>%
ggplot() + 
    geom_histogram(aes(fill = year, 
                       x = x), 
                   binwidth = 1, 
                   position='dodge') + 
    theme_minimal()
```

[image]

gets me almost all the way there. What I want is to be able to add something like `facet_wrap(group~.)` to the end of this to show how these change by group but obviously `group` is not part of the aggregated dataframe.

Right now my best solution is just to show multiple plots like

```
df %>% filter(group==1) # Replace group number here
    group_by(id,year) %>% 
    summarize(x=sum(test_result)) %>%
ggplot() + 
    geom_histogram(aes(fill = year, 
                       x = x), 
                   binwidth = 1, 
                   position='dodge') + 
    theme_minimal()
```

but I'd love to figure out how to put them all in one figure and I'm wondering if maybe the way to do that is to put more of the grouping logic into ggplot?

Comment: If you want a summary per group instead of overall, maybe add `group` to `group_by()` and then facet by that variable?

Comment: I feel so foolish. I swear I tried this and it didn't work but I tried again and it's exactly what I want. :)

Comment: You might want to try `geom_bar` instead of `geom_histogram`.